# Running meteor on linux server

Tags: meteor, deployment, server

I am trying to get my localhost working on my remote (mediatemple) server.

I have bundled it up and have a /myurl.com/bundle folder with the following files.

this folder contains

- main.js
- npm-debug.log
- programs
- server

How do I get this to run?

Comment: did you take a look at meteor Up? https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look in the README inside the bundle folder. Normally everything ist described there to start your app.

Make sure that NODEJS and MONGO is installed on your remote server. This is NOT included in your bundle as well as NODEJS is not present.

If you are running a system like debian or ubuntu normally you can do the installation with

```
apt-get install nodejs mongo
```

Make sure, that the nodejs has release v0.10.36 or v0.10.38

```
node --version
```

At the README you see the necessary ENV-VARS like MONGO_URL and PORT you need to set to start your meteor app.

If you have running a apache server already the PORT 80 is already blocked, so try PORT=3000 to start your meteor app.

Example:

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/yourapp' ROOT_URL="http://yourhost" PORT=3000 node main.js
```

If using as above you do not need to export the ENV-VARS before start

Sometime when starting, there are missing NPM  – you get fiber errors

In that case

```
cd programs/server
npm install
```

and the try start again.

Good luck
Tom

Answer (score 0):

(I'm writing this response assuming that you are not worried about scalability issue, respond in comment if you want to scale your app)

The best option for running a node application, which Meteor application is, is by using forever.

```
npm install forever
forever start simple-server.js
```

If you want to figure out how to see the log files and how to stop/restart your service, you can run `forever --help` to see all the commands.